# Public data is not found

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am in the Google Data Analysis course on Coursera. I am now in the project using Google Bigquery and I am stuck. It's a simple SQL coding, which is:

```
SELECT
    end_station_name
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
```

but I have been getting the error, such as:

> Error running query
> Not found: Dataset bigquery-public-data:london_bicycles was not found in location US

Is it really so? I can't get the data in the US?

Answer (score 1):

That particular dataset is hosted in the EU multiregion.  In the query options, you can select either 'auto-select' or 'EU' as the processing location if you're using the cloud console.